# QSqlRelationalTableModel additional related columns

Tags: python, qt, sqlite, pyqt, pyside

I have a `QSqlRelationalTableModel` setup with a `QSqlRelation` to another table working great. Now, I would like to lookup additional columns for that row on the related table. How do I accomplish this?

Example tables:

```
city ('id', 'name', 'state_id')
state ('id', 'name', 'capital')
```

what I have so far:

```
model = QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel()
model.setTable('city')
model.setRelation(2, QtSql.QSqlRelation("state", "id", "name"))
model.select()
```

Which would give me a row like:

```
| 1 | 'San Francisco' | 'California' |
```

Now I would like to lookup the capital in the state model, from the city table. How do I do this? My understanding of `setRelation` is that it takes the id from the main_table at column X and replaces it with the mapped column, but I don't want to alter the state table. I've looked into the `QSqlRecord` and `QSqlRelation`, but I seem to be missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`QSqlRelationalTableModel` is useful when you have foreign keys in the table you want to display. In your case `capital` is not a column of the `city` table.

You should instead use a `QSqlQueryModel` and `JOIN` the two tables in order to take the columns you wish. Something like this should work

```
model = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
model.setQuery("SELECT city.id, city.name, state.name, state.capital FROM city "
                "INNER JOIN state ON city.state_id = state.id");
model.select()
```

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case. Unfortunately that wont work for me as QSqlQueryModel is read only, and my application is for a editable model (not capital however).

Would it be possible to override the query such that the setRelation portion of the QSqlRelationalTableModel still functions as it currently does?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found to do what I am looking to do is to use a QSqlRelationalTableModel and override the selectStatement.

Failed attempts:

Overload setRelation with additional columns:

```
model.setRelation(2, QtSql.QSqlRelation("state", "id", "name, capital"))
```

While this displays the data, it breaks the QSqlRelationalDelegate if you are using one.

I also experimented with added a method to search through the relationModel, but that seemed like a worse solution than the selectStatement() approach.

```
def getStateForRow(self, row):
    # The state is col 2
    stateModel=self.relationModel(2)
    return stateModel.match(stateModel.index(0,1), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, self.record(row).value(2), flags = QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly)[0]
```

I also looked into QSqlQueryModel per @pnezis's advice, but it says in the docs

> The QSqlQueryModel class provides a read-only data model for SQL result sets...

But it pointed me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I had a similar problem and a solution, which might be of interest.
This applys to Qt Version 5.12 and Python 3.8 (and probably newer versions).

- You can put more than one column name into the third parameter of QtSql.QSqlRelation()

In your case:

```
QtSql.QSqlRelation("state", "id", "name, capital")
```

- Internally the foreign tables get an assigned name like relTblAl_n, so if you have ambiguous column names, you can use it as a prefix

Example:

```
QtSql.QSqlRelation("state", "id", "name, relTblAl_1.capital")
```

- You can also assign an alias, or concatenate columns and arbitrary text (though this might not be portable, "||" works on SQLite and Oracle)

Example:

```
QtSql.QSqlRelation("state", "id", "name || ' Capital: ' || relTblAl_1.capital AS state_information")
```

And now for the best part: **you can put arbitrary SQL in the third parameter!**

In my case, I needed a value from another lookup table, because (to stay close to your database layout) capitals where in another table, with a foreign key pointing from "states" to, lets say, "capitals".

Example:

```
QtSql.QSqlRelation("state", "id", "name, (SELECT capitals.name FROM capitals"
                  " WHERE capitals.id = relTblAl_1.capital_id) as Capital")
```

There is only one problem if you want to edit values through a QTableView: You can edit other columns, but if you try to edit the related column, the model does not know what to do.